# Print the value of focused input in reactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Good evening guys. Need your help. I would like to make two input cells into one like an Excel but dunno how to figure out this when it is focused. I have created the table dynamically and now stuck here .The code is given [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ezdxg224/873/). Can you give any hints to do so? Any reply would be appreciated.

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: you can use `onFocus` attribute in Input tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of focused inputs, you can use 'onFocus'. For example:

```
<input 
  type="text"
  value={this.state.text}
  name="Text"
  onFocus={this.handleFocus}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

handleFocus(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    text: e.target.value
  })
}
```

Comment: does it work if I add it to my code which I provided in description?

Comment: you can always try. :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply